# error=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Tags: vb.net

I have a gridview which when I upload my data and make an attempt to submit it to mysql database I get his error

"error=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index""

Here is the code I am using, and the problem occurs on the address row.

```
   For i = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()

                student_id = GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(i).Text.ToString
                age = GridView1.Rows(1).Cells(i).Text.ToString
               adress = GridView1.Rows(2).Cells(i).Text.ToString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something seems wrong here.
You loop over the rows of the gridview, but then you take the index of the row to access the cells.
Probably you want this

```
For i = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1 
    Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand() 
       .... 
       student_id = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text.ToString 
       age = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text.ToString 
       adress = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text.ToString 
       ....
    End Using
Next
```

Comment: Thanks I just looked at my code before reading your answer and noticed it. But thanks anyway. v. appreciated!